# How to write code varying according to current client/mandant?

Tags: abap

We currently have a SAP System with two different clients 002 and 004 in use. My task is to write a program in ABAP to create a report about user assignments. The report will do mainly the same on both clients, but I have to select different tables on both clients.

Is there a way to distinguish an ABAP code between different clients like:

```
IF client = 002.
* dothis.
ELSE.
* dothatdifferentthing.
ENDIF.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current client is available in field **sy-mandt**.

For example:

```
IF sy-mandt = '002'.
*dothis.
ELSE.
*dothatdifferentthing.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: And 99% of SAP tables include in its key the field mandt or client (the ones that do not include it are client independent) so you can make your code client dependant (avoiding duplication of code) adding 'client = sy-mandt' or 'mandt = sy-mandt' and 'CLIENT SPECIFIED' on every database access (read, update, delete...) See sap help on FROM statement

Comment: The system automatically applies the constraint to SQL-queries, so by default you only get data where `mandt = sy-mandt`

Answer (score 5):

An additional suggestion - try to do this the object-oriented way, stuffing all the common code into an abstract superclass and create two subclasses which carry only the client-dependent code. Then, based on SY-MANDT, instantiate either of the subclasses. This might help reducing duplicate code...